# Is it possible to substitute one color for another on a live webpage using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have a webpage, with the following structure:

```
-index.html
-styles.css
-script.js
```

Of course, my `index.html` includes some imports of styles, such as bootstrap etc.

I have a config per tenant, and each tenant have his or hers own color palete, that should overwrite the default. For an example, lets say that default primary color is #11111. I have no idea what elements/classes use certain HEX color.

I would like to know, if it is possible to change one HEX color for the tenant config color, using code in script.js, after the page is loaded?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. you can do it in variaous ways such as appending new style element to your dom dynamically, cahanging the color usage of elements etc.

Comment: Also it might be a good idea to read into SASS and how bootstrap allows you to customize colors with the usage of SASS